# Can angular and knockout be used in same web application?

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js

I am learning Angular JS and Knockout JS. So usually during interviews I have encountered a question like,

1. Can we use both Angular JS and Knockout JS in the same application at a time.
2. Also what could be the disadvantages and advantages if we do that?
3. If we cannot use both frameworks in the same web application, what are the reasons.

Please help me out.

Comment: Yes you can.  Takes a bit of extra loading but angular in particular plays well with other libraries.

Comment: You encountered this question during a job interview?  It is really unlikely that a production software house would not have settled on one framework or the other.....

Comment: @Claies you missed the point , it's not that they would use both it's about testing applicant knowledge and communication skills

Answer (score 8):

1. Yes you can ("But why would you? AngularJS already has data binding" would be my counter question)
2. Disadvantages

   - Devs must learn two frameworks.
   - As mentioned above, increased loading time.

   Advantages

   - None that I can see.
3. See 1.